# Coroutines in C

Tags: c, library, coroutines

Please have a look at this little coroutines library `ccoro`: http://sam.nipl.net/code/ccoro

I'd appreciate a general code and style review, and your kind comments!

---

`ccoro.h`

```
/*
 * ccoro - Coroutines in C
 * Sam Watkins, 2009
 * this code is public domain
 *
 * ccoro uses setjmp and longjmp to achieve coroutines in plain C.
 */

#ifndef CCORO_H
#define CCORO_H 1
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <setjmp.h>

#if defined (__GNUC__)
#define noret void __attribute__((noreturn))
#else
#define noret void
#endif

extern int coro_pad;
enum { coro_code_done = -1, coro_code_alloc = -2, coro_code_dead = -3 };

typedef struct coro coro;

typedef void (*coro_func)(coro *caller);

struct coro
{
    coro *next;
    coro *prev;
    jmp_buf j;
};

coro *new_coro(coro_func f);
int yield(coro **c);
int yield_val(coro **c, int val);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

---

`ccoro.c`

```
/*/ 2>/dev/null; exec cc -c -Wall -Wextra -O2 ccoro.c ; exit $? # */

/*
 * ccoro - Coroutines in C
 * Sam Watkins, 2009
 * this code is public domain
 *
 * ccoro uses setjmp and longjmp to achieve coroutines in plain C,
 * non-preemptive threading.  It works by allocating each thread some stack
 * space on the normal stack.  It makes sure that each thread has enough space
 * to run using a padding variable, of size 8k by default, which is inserted by
 * a function that starts the thread.  Simple, huh?  It uses some fairly simple
 * trickery to create new threads that don't overlap with the other threads.
 *
 * I don't claim that this code is legal by the book, but it seems to work
 * with at gcc, tcc, tendra and lcc on Linux i386 and x86_64, and with mingw
 * gcc-4.4 and Visual C++ 98 Express on Windows.
 *
 * As is, this requires C99.  To run with C89, use an enum for coro_pad.
 *
 * An earlier version was reported not to work with tendra on netbsd.
 * I have fixed bugs since then so maybe it works now.
 *
 * An earlier version did not work with -O2 on some systems, it seems to be
 * working now.
 *
 * An earlier version did not work with current glibc, it gave an error:
 *   *** longjmp causes uninitialized stack frame ***
 * I have avoided this check by using the internal function __libc_longjmp.
 *
 * TODO use a free-list instead of always allocating new coroutines at the top
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "ccoro.h"

#ifdef __GLIBC__
/* use glibc internal longjmp to bypass fortify checks */
noret __libc_longjmp (jmp_buf buf, int val);
#define longjmp __libc_longjmp
#endif

static void coro_init(void);
static noret new_coro_2(coro_func f, coro *caller);
static noret new_coro_3(coro_func f, coro *caller);
static int yield_val_2(coro *c, int val);

int coro_pad = 8192;
/* enum { coro_pad = 8192 }; */

static int coro_init_done = 0;
static coro main_coro;
static coro *coro_top = &main_coro;
static coro *current_coro = &main_coro;
static coro_func new_coro_f;

void coro_init(void)
{
    main_coro.prev = NULL;
    main_coro.next = NULL;
    coro_init_done = 1;
}

int yield_val_2(coro *c, int val)
{
    coro *me = current_coro;
    int v = setjmp(me->j);

    if (v == 0)                        /* yield */
        longjmp(c->j, val);
    else if (v == coro_code_alloc) {   /* new - this is top */
        coro *caller = current_coro;
        current_coro = me;
        new_coro_2(new_coro_f, caller);
        /* cannot return */
    }
    /* else returned */
    current_coro = me;
    return v;
}

int yield_val(coro **c, int val)
{
    if (*c) {
        int v = yield_val_2(*c, val);
        if (v == coro_code_done)
            *c = NULL;
        return v;
    }
    return coro_code_dead;
}

int yield(coro **c)
{
    return yield_val(c, 1);
}

noret new_coro_3(coro_func f, coro *caller)
{
    coro c;

    current_coro = &c;

    if (coro_top)
        coro_top->next = &c;
    c.prev = coro_top;
    c.next = NULL;
    coro_top = &c;

    (*f)(caller);

    if (current_coro->prev)
        current_coro->prev->next = current_coro->next;
    if (current_coro->next)
        current_coro->next->prev = current_coro->prev;

    if (current_coro == coro_top)
        coro_top = current_coro->prev;

    current_coro = NULL;

    longjmp(caller->j, coro_code_done);  /* finished */
}

noret new_coro_2(coro_func f, coro *caller)
{
    volatile char pad[coro_pad];

    pad[0] = pad[coro_pad-1] = 0;
    new_coro_3(f, caller);
    pad[0] = pad[coro_pad-1] = 0;
    /* cannot return */
}

coro *new_coro(coro_func f)
{
    int v;
    coro *me = current_coro;
    coro *yielder;

    if (!coro_init_done)
        coro_init();
    new_coro_f = f;
    v = setjmp(current_coro->j);
    if (v == 0) {                          /* new */
        if (current_coro == coro_top) {
            new_coro_2(f, current_coro);
        } else {
            longjmp(coro_top->j, coro_code_alloc);
        }
        /* cannot return */
    }
    /* else yielded */
    yielder = current_coro;
    current_coro = me;
    return yielder;
}
```

---

`demo.c`

```
/*/ 2>/dev/null; cc -o demo -Wall -Wextra -O2 demo.c ccoro.o && exec ./demo "$@" ; exit $? # */

/*
 * ccoro - Coroutines in C
 * Sam Watkins, 2009
 * this code is public domain
 *
 * This demo runs three coroutines:
 *   count, print factorials, print fibonacci sequence.
 */

#include <stdio.h>

#include "ccoro.h"

int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    return n * factorial(n-1);
}

int fibonacci(int n)
{
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return n;
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
}

void factorial_coro(coro *caller)
{
    int i;

    for(i=9; i>=0; --i) {
        int j = factorial(i);
        printf("  %d %d\n", i, j);
        yield(&caller);
    }
}

void fibonacci_coro(coro *caller)
{
    int i;

    for(i=1; i<8; ++i) {
        int j = fibonacci(i);
        printf("    %d %d\n", i, j);
        yield(&caller);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    coro *c = new_coro(fibonacci_coro);
    coro *c2 = new_coro(factorial_coro);
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        yield(&c);
        yield(&c2);
    }
    if (c || c2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "the coros did not finish\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: also, don't forget this one!  It is much lighter-weight and less risky. http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html

Comment: One thing I can suggest to myself, to make the internal function names more meaningful.  I prefer to minimize comments, but that means I should use very meaningful identifers so the code can be understood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### `ccoro.h`

```
#define CCORO_H 1
```

Random note, but you don't need to define that to `1`, a simple `#define CCORO_H` would work fine.

```
enum { coro_code_done = -1, coro_code_alloc = -2, coro_code_dead = -3 };
```

I'd make it a little clearer that these are constants. Due to C's general lack of typing or other constructs to make code self-documenting, prefixing constants with `k` or using `ALL_CAPS` is helpful.

---

#### `ccoro.c`

```
static noret new_coro_2(coro_func f, coro *caller);
static noret new_coro_3(coro_func f, coro *caller);
static int yield_val_2(coro *c, int val);
```

I know you mentioned this already, but these function names are meaningless and confusing. Make them more meaningful to make the code clearer.

```
int coro_pad = 8192;
```

What does this do? Add a comment to document this constant's purpose.

Also, `coro_pad` is a constant, right? Why not use `const` to declare it as such?

```
if (v == 0)                        /* yield */
    longjmp(c->j, val);
else if (v == coro_code_alloc) {   /* new - this is top */
    coro *caller = current_coro;
    current_coro = me;
    new_coro_2(new_coro_f, caller);
    /* cannot return */
}
```

Braces, please! If you're going to have an `else` clause with braces, put braces around the `if` clause, too.

```
noret new_coro_3(coro_func f, coro *caller)
{ ... }
```

Honestly, I have *no idea* what this function is doing. Changing the name would help, as mentioned above, but adding some inline comments would be nice, too!

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.  `coro_pad` can potentially be changed by the client before creating any coros, if it will need more stack space per coro, that's why it's not a constant. Other than that, I agree with everything you said and it's very helpful.  To be honest I'll have to have a careful look at that `new_coro_3` myself before I can write good comments for it!